# SQL Server substring with optional character

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I wanted to take the substring of `COLUMN_A` after '#' character.

I used:

```
RIGHT(COLUMN_A, (LEN(COLUMN_A) - CHARINDEX('#', COLUMN_A)))
```

This works fine when `COLUMN_A` has a '#' character. But in some rows, if the '#' is not there, then I get empty result. I tried using `ISNULL()` to handle this, but no luck!

Any advice on how this can be handled?

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement to check if there is a pound sign and return something else:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('#',COLUMN_A) = -1 
  THEN COLUMN_A
  ELSE RIGHT(COLUMN_A, (len(COLUMN_A) - CHARINDEX('#',COLUMN_A)))
END
```